# How to send a message to an actor from outside in Play Framework 2?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, actor

I am new to Akka and trying to write some code in Play Framework 2 in Java and use Akka.
To create an actor and send a test message to it, I have:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        final ActorRef testActor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(TestActor.class), "testActor");
        testActor.tell("hi", ActorRef.noSender());
    }
}
```

This work perfectly fine and I see that my actor received my message, here is the code for my actor:

```
public class TestActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message.toString().equals("hi")){
            System.out.println("I received a HI");
        }else{
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Very simple.
However, If I try to send a message from a controller:

```
public static Result index() {
        final ActorRef testActor = Akka.system().actorFor("testActor");
        testActor.tell("hi", ActorRef.noSender());
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
```

I get this message on terminal:

[INFO] [09/20/2014 11:40:30.850] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://application/testActor] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://application/testActor] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Can someone help me with this? why the first usage works and the second one fails? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to pass ActorRef to controller instead of using actorFor method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `actorFor` method requires the entire path, and your actor lives in the user space, so you have to use `actorFor("/user/testActor")`. Currently you are sending it to `application/testActor`, which would be a top-level actor in the ActorSystem itself.

By the way, `actorFor` is deprecated (at least in the Scala API) and replaced by `actorSelection`.

For more information, refer to the [excellent documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html).

Comment: @Marinus Soutier I have already tried actorSelection. It gives the same result. for some reason I can send a message to that actor from my controller. I used Inbox as a workaround. but I really have to know why it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried changing "testActor" to "/user/testActor" as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

**actorFor** should get the path to the actor which is probably "akka://System/user/testActor". It also does not create the actor, meaning it should be exist.

Anyway, is there a reason that inside the controller you use the **actorFor** and not the **actorOf**? It [had been deprecated](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html#Use_actorSelection_instead_of_actorFor) and shouldn't be use.

Comment: well no specific reason on choosing actorFor. I know that actorOf  creates the actor, which is done in the Global.java. So I am sure that it is created. that's why I use actorFor in my controller.